# Gramjs client.start() works locally but not with docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, telegram

I'm trying to deploy a **NodeJS Gramjs** (a trasposition of Python Telethon package for NodeJS) application and when I test it locally, **Gramjs** can connect to Telegram account without any problem but when I test it in a **Docker** container, it connects but it stucks.

Here are the logs:

```
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.294] [INFO] - [Running gramJS version 2.19.9]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.311] [INFO] - [Connecting to 91.108.56.132:80/TCPFull...]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.313] [DEBUG] - [Connecting]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.332] [DEBUG] - [Finished connecting]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.334] [DEBUG] - [Connection success!]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.334] [DEBUG] - [Already have an auth key ...]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.334] [DEBUG] - [Starting send loop]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.335] [DEBUG] - [Waiting for messages to send... false]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.335] [DEBUG] - [Starting receive loop]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.336] [DEBUG] - [Receiving items from the network...]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.337] [INFO] - [Connection to 91.108.56.132:80/TCPFull complete!]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.358] [INFO] - [Using LAYER 166 for initial connect]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.364] [DEBUG] - [Send InvokeWithLayer]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.369] [DEBUG] - [Assigned msgId = 7333912386031770884 to InvokeWithLayer]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.371] [DEBUG] - [Got 1 message(s) to send]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.372] [DEBUG] - [Encrypting 1 message(s) in 100 bytes for sending]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.375] [DEBUG] - [Sending   InvokeWithLayer]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.386] [DEBUG] - [Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent]
[2024-02-10T10:05:41.386] [DEBUG] - [Waiting for messages to send... false]
```

and it remains stuck here!

This is the simple js file which is supposed to simply send a message to myself:

```
const { TelegramClient } = require("telegram");
const { StoreSession } = require("telegram/sessions");
const input = require("input");
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new TelegramClient(new StoreSession("my_session"), parseInt(process.env.API_ID), process.env.API_HASH, {
    connectionRetries: 5,
});
client.setLogLevel("debug");

(async () => {
    await client.start({
        phoneNumber: async () => await input.text("Please enter your number: "),
        password: async () => await input.text("Please enter your password: "),
        phoneCode: async () => await input.text("Please enter the code you received: "),
        onError: (err) => console.log(err),
    });

    console.log("You should now be connected.");

    await client.sendMessage("me", { message: "test" });
    console.log("Sent to me.");
})()
```

Finally the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /bot

COPY ../bot.example.js ../package.json .
COPY ../my_session ./my_session

ENV API_ID=<hidden> \
    API_HASH=<hidden>

RUN npm install

CMD [ "node", "bot.example.js" ]
```

I also took care of copying the "my_session" folder to the image in order to avoid the need to auth again.

As said, locally it works great and it sends to me the message, yet on docker it stucks...

Any help?
Thank you in advance!